# Artifactory Conda virtual repository with artifact available in multiple inside repos giving checksum mismatch

Tags: conda, artifactory

I'm attempting to include MD5 hashes for packages listed in conda environment files, to ensure that I get the version I was expecting when running against a conda virtual repository in JFrog Artifactory Cloud. I'm getting issues similar to a fixed bug (https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-18411); when I use `conda search` to find the file I get one version from the index, whereas when I download the file it has a different md5sum.

I've found that if I first attempt to download the file from the remote repository which has the correct version then the virtual repository will start serving the correct file, so it looks like the virtual repository defaults to serving a cached file from a later repo rather than downloading from the earlier repo.

Is there any way to disable or workaround this behaviour?

Comment: There is no way to fix this. The workaround is to either delete the artifact from one repo or remove the virtual repo and just add each upstream repo to your sources.